# WinMerge & Encoding

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, utf-8, winmerge

I have a problem with WinMerge (or more specific: WinMergeU). I have several php files that have the same content up to the chosen encoding. 
How can I tell WinMerge to ignore the encoding?
If this is not possible: Is there an alternative, that can ignore the encoding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an option in `File > File encoding...` that lets you select the loading codepage for the *left* or the *right* file. If you select just one of those and set the encoding so that it matches the other one, it should solve your problem.